# Can I make fully transparent glass with no refractions?

Tags: transparency, lighting, glass

I made a stove. I put a light inside, for the light that's on when you're cooking something. I just found out how to make the window in the door glass to see trough it, but now there's the problem that it's very distorted with refractions and I also can't see the baking tray I put inside. Is there a way to make the glass fully transparent?

[image]

[image: As you can see the tray is not visible whenever the door is]

Comment: Try reducing the IOR of your glass - an IOR of exactly 1 gives zero refraction.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett It turns out that an ior of 1 means that a glass pane is practically invisible in the scene, so if you don't want to mess with the glass-shadow problem in cycles you can just leave the window empty or use the fairly standard glossy/transparent bsdf workaround.

Comment: are you using cycles or eevee?  The solution for transparency and refraction is different in each.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image in your question, it doesn’t look like what’s causing the issue is *refraction*, but *reflection*. It’s hard to tell exactly why you’re getting so much reflection without more information about your specific materials and scene, but there are a few possibilities:

1. The normals on your glass pane could be pointing the wrong direction. Try recalculating them by selecting the faces in Edit Mode and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.
2. The IOR on your material could be too high. The IOR of real glass should be about 1.5, but you could try lowering it closer to 1.0 to see if that looks better in your scene.
3. You might simply want less strong specular reflection than what the Principled BSDF provides. The Principled BSDF generally tries to be physically accurate, so deviating from it is likely to produce less technically realistic results, but you may want to do that, anyway, for artistic reasons.

   In that case, you can manually combine a Refraction BSDF with a Glossy BSDF to get finer control over the amount of reflection:

   [image]

   By using a lower IOR for the Fresnel mix factor than you use for the Refraction BSDF, you can artificially lower the amount of reflection as low as you desire.